# What is an 'aliased local shared_ptr' in this example

Tags: c++, alias, smart-pointers, cpp-core-guidelines

I have a question about an example in the Cpp Core Guidelines. In [R.37: Do not pass a pointer or reference obtained from an aliased smart pointer](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r37-do-not-pass-a-pointer-or-reference-obtained-from-an-aliased-smart-pointer) there is the following example:

```
// global (static or heap), or aliased local ...
shared_ptr<widget> g_p = ...;

void f(widget& w)
{
    g();
    use(w);  // A
}

void g()
{
    g_p = ...; // oops, if this was the last shared_ptr to that widget, destroys the widget
}
```

And I don't understand what is meant with 'aliased local' in the first comment. Is it connected to aliasing pointer types like

```
using WidgetPtr = std::shared_ptr<widget>;
```

or am I completely on the wrong track? I think I understand this example for global shared_ptr, but not for aliased local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const shared_ptr<widget>& alias = g_p;` is an alias for `g_p`. There is no aliased local `shared_ptr` in the code, they just mention it for completeness: You can't side-step this issue by creating a reference or pointer to the global variable (more or less just giving it a different name - an alias - in local scope).

It has nothing to do with type aliases like your `WidgetPtr` (although one could of course *use* type aliases in creating a local alias to a global `shared_ptr`, but that's orthogonal).

In other words: If this is bad code:

```
void bad_code()
{
    // BAD: passing pointer or reference obtained from a nonlocal smart pointer
    //      that could be inadvertently reset somewhere inside f or it callees
    f(*g_p);

    // BAD: same reason, just passing it as a "this" pointer
    g_p->func();
}
```

Then this is also bad code:

```
void also_bad_code(bool maybe)
{
    const auto& maybe_g_p_alias = maybe ? g_p : someOtherValue; // Potentially aliases g_p

    f(*maybe_g_p_alias);

    maybe_g_p_alias->func();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`std::shared_ptr` will automatically destroy the object it points to when all the `std::shared_ptr` that point to the object are destroyed or reassigned to something else.

This means that if you store a pointer or a reference to an object managed by a `std::shared_ptr` (this is an *aliased* pointer), it may suddenly becomes dangling if the `std::shared_ptr` managing it is destroyed or modified.

You left the most important part of the example out, but in a case like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> shared = std::make_shared<int>(7);
int& ptr = *shared;
shared = nullptr;
```

When `shared` is set to `nullptr`, the objects it pointed to is immediately destroyed, meaning that any pointer to it (like `ptr`) is now dangling, and reading or writing to it will result in UB.

Comment: You are correct that references or pointers to an object stored in a `shared_ptr` are aliases and that they are a motivation for this rule, but the guideline is specifically _talking_ about aliases to the `shared_ptr` (or the `shared_ptr` itself).

Answer (score 0):

"alias" in this case means "another name for the same object".

`f` takes a reference `widget& w` as parameter. So if you call it with `f(g_p)` then inside `f` both `g_p` and `w` refer to the same object `g_p`. `w` is an alias for `g_p`. The guidelines say that you should not call `f(g_p)` (g_p being a global object) and you should also not call `f(w)` (w being an aliased local/a local alias to the global object).